# how to maintain order of elements using snowflake object_construct() function instead of sorting by the keys?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, object-construction

Following snowflake query returns the JSON structure but output is sorted by the keys. How not to sort by the keys but retains the order? Is there any parameter setting that needs to be set?

```
select
object_construct
(
  'entity',  'XYZ',
  'allowed',  'Yes',
  'currency', 'USD',
  'statement_month','July, 2020'
 )
```

Output: --it sorts by the keys

```
{
  "allowed": "Yes",
  "currency": "USD",
  "entity": "XYZ",
  "statement_month": "July, 2020"
}
```

Expected Output: --same order as specified

```
{
  "entity": "XYZ",
  "allowed": "Yes",
  "currency": "USD",
  "statement_month": "July, 2020"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

JSON is an unordered collection of name and values. Order cannot be guaranteed in JSON.

*The constructed object does not necessarily preserve the original order of the key-value pairs.*

You can do it like as below

```
SELECT mytable:entity::string as entity,
mytable:allowed::string as allowed,
mytable:currency::string as currency,
mytable:statement_month::string as statement_month
from
(select
object_construct
(
  'entity',  'XYZ',
  'allowed',  'Yes',
  'currency', 'USD',
  'statement_month','July, 2020'
 ) mytable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but goal is to produce a JSON output. I think what you've is tabular.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no

Usage notes:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html#usage-notes

The constructed object does not necessarily preserve the original **order** of the key-value pairs.

same for PARSE_JSON Usage notes:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html#usage-notes

The **order** of the key-value pairs in the string produced by TO_JSON is not predictable.

Comment: Correct. That's what I know but just wanted to see if any ways out there.Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

The order was found to be maintained when using object_construct(*):

```
WITH base AS (               
SELECT 'XYZ' "entity", 'Yes' "allowed", 'USD' "currency", 'July, 2020' "statement_month")
SELECT object_construct(*) FROM base;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants the original sort order maintained.  Not a consistent sort order applied.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to maintain a sort order to the entire contents of the object but there is a useful trick to ensure you can put a specific field at in first position of the object, say for example a record type identifier.

This can improve human readability

The sort Snowflake applies is case sensitive with UPPERCASE sorted first.

So both these examples return the same sort order

```
   select object_construct('First_key','foo','second_key', 'bar')
/* Returns {
  "First_key": "foo",
  "second_key": "bar"
} */

select object_construct('second_key', 'bar','First_key','foo')

/* Also Returns {
  "First_key": "foo",
  "second_key": "bar"
} */
```